# i can't sure how many numbers should input with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I can't sure how many numbers will input in the main programing.
For example,I maybe input one or two numbers in the array.

```
float p[1];
for (int z = 0 ; z <=1 ; z++)
{
    scanf("%f",&p[z]);
}
```

in this code,if i just input one number,the for-loop will continue running until I input another number.
how can i do?

Comment: `z<1` instead of `z<=1`

Comment: You cannot. There has to be some kind of indicator to show the end of input. PS: How do you enter the input? `<number> <number>` or some other way like `<number>\n<number>`

Comment: And why are you using `%f` instead of `%d`?

Comment: `int p[1];` --> `float p[2];`

Answer (score 3):

In general, the user has to tell the program that there is no more input, usually by doing one of the following:

- Entering a value that's outside the range of expected values (for example, if you expect your inputs to all be greater than `0`, then an input value of `0` could signal end of input).  This is usually not the most practical approach, especially with floating-point input.
- Signalling an end-of-file condition from the keyboard.  On Linux, this is done by typing `Ctrl-D`, while on Windows it's done by typing `Ctrl-Z`.  The advantage of this approach is that it works for both interactive input and file-based input.

The `scanf` function returns the number of successful conversions and assignments; it will return 0 if the input doesn't match the conversion specifier, and EOF on end-of-file or error.  That leads to logic like the following:

```
float p[N]; // for some number N
size_t z = 0;

while ( z < N && scanf( "%f", &p[z] ) == 1 )
  z++;
```

This will first check to make sure `z` is less than `N`; if so, it will attempt to read the next input into `p[z]`.  If the read is successful (1 successful conversion and assignment), it will increment `z` and loop again.

If the read fails (either due to EOF or bad input), it will exit the loop.

**EDIT**

If you're entering multiple values on a line, another approach is to read your input as a line of text, and then parse out individual numbers.  Here's an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
  char input[SIZE+1]; // for some size SIZE, single line of text input, 
                      // +1 for 0 terminator
  float p[N];         // for some size N
  size_t z = 0;

  /** 
   * Instead of scanf, use fgets to read a line of input
   * from the input stream.  Go until z == N or 
   * there's no more input.
   */
  while( z < N && fgets( input, sizeof input, stdin ) != NULL )
  {
    const char *delimiter = " \t";

    /**
     * Break the input line into *tokens* separated by spaces or tabs
     * (note that this modifies the input buffer by overwriting
     * space and tab characters with 0)
     */
    char *token = strtok( input, delimiter );

    /**
     * Loop while z < N and token is not NULL.
     */
    while ( z < N && token )
    {
      char *chk = NULL;

      /**
       * Convert the token (which is a string) to the 
       * equivalent floating-point value.  If the token
       * contains any characters that don't belong in a
       * floating-point constant, the chk variable will be
       * set to point to that character.
       */
      double val = strtod( token, &chk );

      /**
       * On a successful conversion, chk should point to either
       * a whitespace character or the 0 terminator. 
       */
      if ( *chk != 0 && !isspace( *chk ))
      {
        /**
         * For this example we simply discard the bad input and keep processing
         */
        fprintf( stderr, "%s is not a valid float value - discarding\n", token );
      }
      else
      {
        p[z++] = value;
      }
      /**
       * NULL tells strtok to keep reading from the end of the
       * previous token in the buffer
       */
      token = strtok( NULL, delimiter );
    }
  }
  /**
   * Do something interesting with your p array
   */

  return 0;
}
```

This way, if you enter your data like

```
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 ...
```

this code will process each of those inputs until it reaches the end of the input.

One edge condition that's not being handled in this example is if your input line is larger than `SIZE` characters, and you wind up splitting a token.  In other words, your buffer is sized to hold 80 characters but you wind up typing 90 characters, and one of your inputs straddles that boundary.  There are several ways around that, but I'm trying to keep the example as simple as I can.

If you come away from this with the impression that interactive input processing in C is tedious and error-prone, well, you're right.  It is.  Something I should have mentioned earlier is that `scanf` is not a great tool for handling interactive input; it lacks some of the error handling ability in the code above.

Comment: hi,thanks for your answer.
maybe it's a little misconception.in this case,my partner advises me to try " scanf("%s ", p[N]) ; "
and judge the string"p[N]" 。
following it,I will input two numbers"11 10" or one number "11" .because I use space to separate  two numbers.
so, if I add a judgement before the main code to judge the p[N]
I can't sure would it success ?
sorry , i can't express my meaning absolutely.

or the other way is use the function "getline" , but i can't find how to include it from the dev c++

Comment: I really appreciate you ." scanf() " it's a very fundamental tool for freshman like me.